# Why can’t I stream an mp4 from my RPI by opening it in the browser?

Tags: pi-4, python-3, video, streaming-video

I’m new to self-hosting and am still learning what is and isn’t possible. I have a raspberrypi 4b and am running raspberry piOS Lite (bullseye). As an experiment, I uploaded an mp4 to my RPI and then started a server using `python3 -m http.server 8080`  and then accessed the file directly on my computer at raspberrypi.local:8080/videofile.mp4

When I do this, the link opens and the video tries to play but just keeps loading infinitely. If I download the file and open it locally it plays fine.

Why isn’t this possible? Is the RPI not fast enough to stream the video directly? Or is the issue the python server? Is software like jellyfin required to set something like this up?

Comment: so it never plays, or you didn't wait for it to fully load? Is this in a browser?

Comment: It never plays, though I only waited about 10-15 minutes. Yes this is in a browser (chrome) and I have the same result on a phone (safari).

Comment: how long is the video and what's the file size ... in your browser developer tools, do you see any errors?

Comment: The video is about 45 minutes long and the file size is 207MB. There are no errors in the dev tools.

Comment: I think I get what you are hinting at though - when I access the file directly does it load the whole thing into the browser before playing? It did take a while to copy over to the rpi4. And it takes specialized software to stream the video while loading it?

Comment: 207MB isn't that big. PI4's gigabit ethernet should be able to handle that in seconds

Comment: Maybe the python http server is slowing it down? Outside of something like jellyfin (I don’t need the library interface), what’s the best way to host a video file to serve directly to a browser?